# Unit test fails with contradicting message

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, moq, type-assertion

I have an object called `Content` that inherits from `ContentBase`.

`ContentBase` is a basic class with few properties.
`Content` is entirely empty. It just inherits everything from `ContentBase`.

```
public class ContentBase
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Application { get; set; }
    public virtual string Property1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Content : ContentBase
{
}
```

using Moq I have this test:

```
    [Test]
    public void AreEqual_Test()
    {
        var c1 = new Content() { CultureCode = "Code", ResourceKey = "key", ResourceType = "type", ResourceValue = "value" };
        var c2 = new Content() { CultureCode = "Code", ResourceKey = "key", ResourceType = "type", ResourceValue = "value" };

        Assert.AreEqual(c1, c2);
    }
```

Which fails with this message:

```
Expected: <WebPortal.DomainModels.PresentationModel.Content>
But was:  <WebPortal.DomainModels.PresentationModel.Content>

at 
NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(Object actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args)
   at WebPortal.DomainModels.Tests.PresentationModel.ContentTests.AreEqual_Test() in ContentTests.cs: line 16
```

This didn't use to happen when Content didn't inherit from ContentBase but still, I find the error message ridiculous.

The Content class contains this Equals:

```
 public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var content = (Content)obj;
        return this.ResourceKey == content.ResourceKey && this.ResourceType == content.ResourceType && this.CultureCode == content.CultureCode;
    }

 public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode() + this.Application.GetHashCode();
    }
```

The failing Assert does NOT trigger the Equals method

```
Assert.AreEqual(c1, c2);
```

But the Assert below does trigger the Equals and the tests passes:

```
Assert.IsTrue(c1.Equals(c2));
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I can only assume that AreEqual will do a reference check on the 2 objects which are clearly of different references

Comment: That wouldn't explain the exception, though.  The exception seems to imply that the types don't agree.  I've seen exceptions like this where the two types specified in the error message appear to be the same; very aggravating.

Comment: This test used to pass but it suddenly stopped and that's why I'm confused. AreEqual didn't use to do a reference check...

Comment: @RobertHarvey NUnit uses ToString method of the objects to display the error message. It returns the type name by default.

Comment: Assert.AreEqual tests for equality, not sameness (reference equality). Assert.AreSame, is used for that. However, AreEqual does default to sameness for classes since reference equality is the default implementation for those.

Comment: It would probably be helpfull to post your ContentBase and Content classes. Complete or with some unimportant stuff removed if you're worried about showing your cards...

Comment: Question updated with ContentBase and Content classes

Comment: have you put a breakpoint into the Equals method and verified that it is executed in your unittest?

Comment: Equals doesn't execute during Assert.AreEqual

Comment: I can't reproduce it. The test works if I add Equals method and it hits the breakpoint inside whetever they inherit ContentBase or not. Maybe there is another mistake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried overriding `GetHashCode`? It is highly recommended to override this method when overriding `Equals` since when the hashcode of different objects don't match, `Equals` will never be called.

This could be what's happening when calling

```
 Assert.AreEqual(c1, c2);
```

As a side note, your Equals implementation doesn't follow the [Guarantees of Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already override GetHashCode.
I will update my question

Comment: I was thinking of using the ReSharper default implementation of the Equals and the GetHashcode but I am afraid the Comparer classes might be affected... I was afraid I'd break existing functionality